# forEach Return for of Loop Equivalent

Tags: ecmascript-6

Just needing to understand better use of new for loops in ES5/ES6.
I've read somewhere about the code above to modify the items array of objects.

```
var selected = [1, 2, 4, 6],
    items = [
        { id: 1, selected: false }, 
        { id: 2, selected: false }, 
        { id: 3, selected: false }, 
        { id: 4, selected: false }, 
        { id: 5, selected: true }, 
        { id: 6, selected: false }
    ]
    set = new Set(selected)

items.forEach(a => a.selected = set.has(a.id))
```

My question is, what is the for of loop equivalent of the forEach statement above?

```
for(let [index, value] of items.entries()) {
    return value.selected = set.has(value.id)
}
```

Comment: Why put that `return` in there? Notice that in `forEach`, the callback return value is ignored anyway.

Comment: No need to use `.entries()` when you don't need an index. Just do `for (const value of items) …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted is very close-- the only problem I see is that you attempt to `return`, which will exit the entire function (and thus loop) prematurely.  This is because the loop isn't calling any new function on each iteration, so the `return` leaves the function in which the `for` begins iterating.  If you remove the `return` from your initial attempt, it functions correctly and as expected.

```js
var selected = [1, 2, 4, 6],
    items = [
        { id: 1, selected: false }, 
        { id: 2, selected: false }, 
        { id: 3, selected: false }, 
        { id: 4, selected: false }, 
        { id: 5, selected: true }, 
        { id: 6, selected: false }
    ]
    set = new Set(selected)

// items.forEach(a => a.selected = set.has(a.id))

for(let [index, value] of items.entries()) {
    value.selected = set.has(value.id)
}

console.log(items);
```